# Issue with POWER9 setup for CUDA in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I am following the instructions in [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#power9-setup) section of NVIDIA's Linux installation support.

I have so far successfully installed CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04, and created the nvidia-persistenced.service file as indicated in the instructions. However, when I run the following command in the folder containing that file:

```
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-persistenced
```

I get

```
Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument
```

To confirm I'm in the right folder, and the file has the right name, the output of `ls` is:

```
nvidia-persistenced.service
```

and the content of the file I see by writing `sudo gedit nvidia-persistenced.service` is:

```
Unit]
Description=NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nvidia-persistenced/nvidia-persistenced.pid
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, taking the time to properly document your problem already gives you the solution you need. While writing, I realised the content of the file was copy-pasted incorrectly. The first line was

```
Unit]
```

while it should have been

```
[Unit]
```

After this correction, the problem was solved. I hope this may help other people, puzzled for a similar silly mistake.